# Sending email when a dropdown item is selected through a Sheet script

Tags: javascript, email, google-sheets

I am trying to send an email to the address supplied in column A when the Status drop down in column H has been set to "Completed". Here is what I have so far:

```
function onOpen() {
sendemail();
}


// This constant is written in column C for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';
var COMPLETED = 'Completed';
/**
* Sends non-duplicate emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
*/
function sendemail() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
 var numRows = 400; // Number of rows to process
 var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3); //grabbing ranges 
 of values to get
 var data = dataRange.getValues(); //getting values
 var status = sheet.getRange(startRow, 8, numRows, 1); //grabbing ranges of 
 //values to get
 var data_status = status.getValues(); //getting values

//logic: if a field is populated and both Column C isn't populated, and 
//Status is Completed, populate corresponding row in column C and send email.
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
var row = data[i];
var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
var message = "";
var emailSent = row[2]; // Third column
   if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT && data_status == COMPLETED) { // Prevents 
       sending duplicates
       var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet';
       MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
  // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is 
     interrupted
     SpreadsheetApp.flush();
     }
    }
  }
```

This code is heavily influenced from google and I am able to grab all of the info from column H, I'm just unsure of what I am doing wrong. The issue is that it's not working. If I take out the and section of the if statement, it will work just fine, and If I debug the code I can see the array of values given to me from column H. For each "completed" value I need it to send the email, however I don't want the email to be sent if the status is set to completed and the Column C has the value EMAIL_SENT Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your script is almost complete. I think that the script works by modifying one part. So how about this modification?

#### Modification point :

- In your script, `data_status` is 2 dimensional array. And when the value of each row is compared to "COMPLETED", whole array is comparing.

In order to reflect above to your script, please modify as follows.

From :

```
if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT && data_status == COMPLETED) {
```

To :

```
if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT && data_status[i][0] == COMPLETED) {
```

If this didn't work, please tell me. I would like to modify it.